# dajaneiro not autocompleting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: django, sublimetext3

After installing Dajaneiro in Sublime Text 3 it is not Autocompleting in Sublime Text 3 under Linux.  What is wrong?

Comment: what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I reinstalled both sublime and dajaneiro and tab autocompletion still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom right of your SublimeText window, there is an option to set the syntax (e.g. Python, C++, etc.). Make sure you set it to the appropriate value, depending on if you're working with Django Python or Django HTML.

Comment: thanks @ubadub sublime text community the best.